# jQuery .append() is not appending anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery

since our FF updated to ver 106 an internal application has some strange behavior.

I have a textfield in my webapp where I type in data -> then press a button(checkrottnodespeed).
First empty the div (`configuratorresult`) in case something is in there. Set it to not `async`. post the data to my php function which returns an html table filled with data from my database. after that I append the data to the empty div.

```
$("#checkrootnodespeed").click(function() {
    $("#configuratorresult").empty();
    $.ajaxSetup({async:false});
$.post("ajax.php?f=rnpresulttable", $("#konfiguratorform").serialize(), function (data) {
    $("#configuratorresult").append(data);
    console.log(data);
});
```

in the next step i foreach trough the table that was generated, grapping some information and post it to another php function which executes some telnetcommands and returns data for the row one after another.

```
var lines=$("#generatedtablefromPHPfunction").find("tr");
for (i=1;i<lines["length"];i++) {
 var error=false;
 some checks.....for "somedataineed"
 $.post("ajax.php?f=rnpuplinkspeed", { somedataineed }, function (result) {
   $("#generatedtablefromPHPfunction")
     .find("tr").eq(i).find("td").eq(4).html(result);
   });
 if (error) continue;

 }
 $.ajaxSetup({async:true});
});
```

This worked for years. After I clicked the button, my first php function returned the table, showed it in the dom. after that the rows got filled with the missing information one after another.

Now, with FF 106 the table is only displayed when every information for every single row is received and I don't understand why its not showing it right after appending it to the empty div anymore and fill the missing data afterwards. My console.log(data); in the first function shows the whole table. so the table data is available in the DOM, but its not displayed...

Any Ideas?

I tried hiding the div and showing it again `($("##configuratorresult").css("display", "none");` and .`.css("display", "block")`

Comment: If you remove the `console.log(data);` does this work?

Comment: This is not how to do AJAX. Are you seriously running ajax in a for loop?
You need to get all the data in one go and THEN loop

Comment: `async:false` has been deprecated for over a decade. Maybe (hopefully) the latest Firefox finally removed the support for it.

Comment: Suggest alternate `$("#configuratorresult").toggle(false); and `.toggle(true)` note `toggle` is aliased by `.show()` `.hide()` and you have two `##` there

Comment: Also return just data if you want speed. Then you RENDER the data into the table instead

Comment: Why not just `var lines=$("#generatedtablefromPHPfunction").find("tr").each(function(row){...`
`